# Adjacency matrix from geographics

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, geographics

The following code shows the map of a number of cities in a country having a population between a specified minimum and maximum value.

```
MyCountry = "UnitedStates";
CityList = CityData[{All, MyCountry}];
MaxPopulation = 50000000;
MinPopulation = 500000;
(* Select from the list of cities those whose population is between \
the min and max prefixed values*)
SelectedCities = 
  Select[CityList, 
   QuantityMagnitude[CityData[#, "Population"]] >= MinPopulation && 
     QuantityMagnitude[CityData[#, "Population"]] <= 
      MaxPopulation &];
Show[
 GeoGraphics[
  Polygon[GeoVariant[Entity["Country", MyCountry], "PrincipalArea"]],
  GeoBackground -> 
   GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
     "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}, GeoZoomLevel -> 10]
  ],
 GeoBubbleChart[
  SelectedCities -> EntityValue[SelectedCities, "Population"],
  GeoBackground -> None,
  (*GeoRange\[Rule]{{49.45,51.55},{1.6,7.5}},*)
  BubbleSizes -> {0.03, 0.03},
  ChartStyle -> "SolarColors"],
 ImageSize -> {2000, 1125}
 ]
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to build the adjacency matrix of a graph having as vertices SelectedCities and an edge for each pair of vertices if there exists a direct connection (e.g., a motorway) between the corresponding cities.

Is there a way to do it by using geographics?

Comment: I haven't been able to formulate an answer yet, but as a suggestion, have you looked at the built in `TravelDirections[]` function? [documentation for TravelDirections](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDirections.html)

Comment: If you wanted a weighted agency matrix corresponding to the distance between cities, you could do something like `weightedAdjMat =  Table[If[i === j, Infinity, TravelDirections[{i, j}]["TravelDistance"]], {i, SelectedCities}, {j, SelectedCities}] ;

   WeightedAdjacencyGraph@weightedAdjMat`

Something I noticed though is `TravelDirections` does not give the same distance for a->b and b->a, but you could remove this (if you don't care about that) by just reflecting the adjacency matrix about the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David! This is a good idea, indeed, there is still a problem. The "TravelDirections" between i and j could be "simple" (i.e., it goes from i to j without crossing another city q in SelectedCities, different from i and j), or "complex" (i.e., it crosses at least one q). In the first case, we should put 1 for the term (i,j) of the adjacency matrix; in the second case we should put infinity. Then, in order to build the adjacency matrix by following your idea, we should be able to address the question: How to know if a city q in SelectedCities is in TravelDirections(i,j)?

Comment: So I tried first doing this with `GeoNearest` but I kept getting the message `GeoNearest::servermessage: Server message: Internal server error.`

So instead I extract the geo coordinates from the travel path, and then calculate their distance to each city in `SelectedCities`. In the example below, I just calculate this for one path and for one city in selected cities. This is a pretty slow method however, since you'd have to do it for every element of the adjacency matrix and every city. https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dtrimas/Published/nearestPathPointToCity.nb

Comment: Calculating this for every element of the adjacency matrix and every city would be (37*36)/2 * (37-2) = 23310 seperate calculations. The example calculation in the notebook I linked took ~2 s on my computer, so all 23310 would take about 13 h to calculate

Comment: You could also try using the starting and ending coordinates provided in the `TravelDirections[{a,b}]["Dataset"]` property and see which city lies closest to each of those start and end points. And then if that city is part of your `SelectedCities` list.

Comment: Thanks David! Your idea seems very interesting. I give a try!